# Generate dynamic XY coordinate labels for dataframe corners in ArcGIS layout

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, dynamic, xy, data-frame

I need to label the four corners of a dataframe as shown in the image. Can this be done with dynamic text scripts?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is documented in the [help file](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s900000013000000) in the second to last table. I believe you're looking for

`<dyn type="dataFrame" name="DataFrameName" property="upperLeft" units="dms" decimalPlaces="4"/>`

and similar (lowerLeft, upper/lowerRight).

Comment: +1 I don't recall ever having seen that very useful help page.